# question about python and opencv for merge images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I wrote this code by python and opencv
I have 2 images (first is an image from football match 36.jpg) :

[image: 36.jpg]

and (second is pitch.png  an image (Lines of football field (Red Color)) with `png` format = without white background) :

[image: pitch.png]

With this code , I selected 4 coordinate points in both of the 2 images (4 corners of the right penalty area)
and then, with ( cv2.warpPerspective ) and showing it , we can show that first image from (Top View)
as below:

[image: top view]

My question is, what changes do I need to make in my code so that the red colored lines from the second image appear on the first image in the same way as the images below (drawn in the Paint app):

[image: desired]

this is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__' :

 # Read source image.
 im_src = cv2.imread('c:/36.jpg')
 # Four corners of penalty area in first image
 pts_src = np.array([[314, 108], [693, 108], [903, 493],[311, 490]])

 # Read destination image.
 im_dst = cv2.imread('c:pitch.png')
 # Four corners of right penalty area in pitch image.
 pts_dst = np.array([[480, 76],[569, 76],[569, 292],[480, 292]])

 # Calculate Homography
 h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

 # Warp source image to destination based on homography
 im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))

 # Display images
 cv2.imshow("Source Image", im_src)
 cv2.imshow("Destination Image", im_dst)
 cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out)

 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: crosspost including answer: https://forum.opencv.org/t/warpperspective-but-inverse-homography/5547

Comment: related previous question by same user, different account (deleted on SO...): https://forum.opencv.org/t/find-points-of-4-corners/5437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your source and destination images and points. Then, warp the source image:

```
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]), borderValue=[255,255,255])
```

and add this code

```
mask = im_out[:,:,0] < 100

im_out_overlapped = im_dst.copy()
im_out_overlapped[mask] = [0,0,255]
```

[image: Overlapped warped image]

Comment: thanks you , your solution was complete , is there a way that  dont be need to write that 4 corners coordinates? and it find automatically

Comment: that is a completely different question, which you asked before using a different account, and then deleted (which you shouldn't)

Comment: @user8190410 you don't need to swap the arguments to `findHomography`. you only need to invert the homography into `warpPerspective` (use `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` for a flag)

Comment: and "add this" is where? Also in your variables im_out_overlapped is not use, or not explicitly. Could you complete the answer for futures visits?